# Can a set be open with respect to a subset?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm reading Bloch's First Course in Geometric Topology and I came across this practice problem:

"$1.2.1$ Show that the following sets are open in $\mathbb{R}^2$:
(1) the complement of a single point in $\mathbb{R}^n$..."

However, I thought that sets can be open relative only to supersets - that is, that the question itself has a typo, and should read

"$1.2.1$ Show that the following sets are open in $\mathbb{R}^2$:
(1) the complement of a single point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}$..."

Is this right? Is openness only with respect to supersets? Or, does this question make sense, and I misinterpreted it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the errata](http://faculty.bard.edu/bloch/topgeom_errata.pdf).  It's the first item listed.

In case that link ever dies: It's a typo.  It should read "a single point in $\mathbb{R}^2$"

My advice going forward: download that pdf and either print it out or have it in a privileged place on your computer so you can refer back to it.

Comment: Wow, where and how did you find this? I had no idea this existed. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @trytryagain It's pretty common for textbook authors to publish errata online for their texts.  I just copied "Bloch's First Course in Geometric Topology" from your question, and pasted it into an internet search with the word "errata".  That link was the first result that appeared.  And you're welcome.  Hopefully that knowledge helps in the future too.

Comment: I had no idea errata were that common. I'll definitely keep that in mind next time I find myself doubting a textbook! Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It does seem like there's a typo and the question should read:

> Show that the following sets are open in $\mathbb R^2$: (1) the complement of a single point in $\mathbb R^2$ [or $\mathbb R \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^2$]...

Openness is "with respect to superset" as you say, or more precisely, it's with respect to some *topology* defined on the superset, i.e. a special kind of collection of subsets of that superset; namely, a set $A\subseteq X$ is open with respect to the topology $\tau$ on $X$ if it is an element of $\tau$. So it makes no sense to be asked whether a set that is not a subset of $X$ is open w.r.t. $\tau$.